# Punctuation after "both"

Tags: commas

I was completing an ACT test and ran across this question that stumbled me...

**Both the posterns and the towers served as defensive positions for protecting Rome.**

I thought there should be commas around the posterns and towers making the sentence the following:

**Both, the posterns and the towers, served as defensive positions for protecting Rome.**

However, the test disagrees but I thought that the posterns and towers are nonessential so they should be surrounded by commas, can anyone explain why not? Thanks.

Comment: Nonessential? They are the subjects of the sentence! You could turn it round - **The posterns and the towers both served...**

Comment: Commas usually correspond with a verbal pause. Read the sentence out loud with a pause at each comma. It sounds weird like that, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second version uses the pronoun "both" as the subject; this is incoherent unless the context has already established what "both" refers to .

It might be appropriate if the text had already discussed the posterns and the towers, so that it was reasonably clear that "both" referred to; but the writer felt that the reader might not be quite clear, so expanded it with "the posterns and the towers" in apposition.

In any other case, the subject is "Both the posterns and the towers", and does not want a comma. "Both" in this case is not a pronoun but a quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the answer per se; however, the question itself is poorly written utilizing "the" twice is redundant; and might possibly preclude a need for commas altogether.